# Deserialise array of BSON objects as root object in Java?

Tags: java, android, serialization, jackson, bson

My goal is to deserialise a BSON array of documents on Android. When the outer array is anonymous the deserialisation fails (trying to deserialise to `CustomObject[].class`). When the array is wrapped in an object with a key containing the array it works (deserialising to `WrapperObject.class`).

In JSON the object would look like this:

```
[{"id":....},{"id":....},{"id":....}....]
```

According to the [BSON Specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) the BSON array is a regular BSON document with integer values for keys. In other words the same object in BSON looks like this:

```
{"0":{"id":....},"1":{"id":....},"2":{"id":....}....}
```

I was trying to deserialise the above using bson4jackson when it threw a "**Can not deserialize instance of *x* out of START_OBJECT token**" error and in the stacktrace I noticed the unexpected token was a "**0**" - the BSON representation for the beginning of an array.

My solution, for now, is to wrap the array in a new root object which, in JSON, would look like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":....},{"id":....},{"id":....},....]}
```

Can you set bson4jackson, or any other deserialisation library for Java, to treat the root object as an array and deal with it as is, without wrapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that bson4jackson is a low-level library which does not know about the type of the object currently being parsed. In BSON arrays are objects and bson4jackson just assumes that every document has an object as its root.

However, there is a workaround for this. Jackson calls the low-level parser's `isExpectedStartArrayToken()` method whenever an array is read. So, it is possible for bson4jackson to switch to array parsing if the current object is a document, but an array is expected.

The fix has just been implemented. For further details see:
https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson/issues/31